# Replacing Scripts in Admin Load_Scripts

Tags: plugin-development, wp-admin, wp-enqueue-script

I'm currently creating a plugin that requires me to overwrite one of the Wordpress admin panel javascript files. I have recreated the file with the changes, I need to know how to replace the existing file that gets loaded in load_scripts.php (the script needs to be added in the same order).

I was hoping something like this would do the job:

wp_register_script('admin-widgets', WP_PLUGIN_URL. '/oak-automated-sidebars/oak-widgets.js');
wp_enqueue_script('admin-widgets');

But it doesn't seem to work, the original script is still loaded. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first  deregister the script using wp_deregister_script

```
 wp_deregister_script( 'admin-widgets' );
```

then use your code to re-register the script using your own js file:

```
wp_register_script('admin-widgets', WP_PLUGIN_URL. '/oak-automated-sidebars/oak-widgets.js'); 
wp_enqueue_script('admin-widgets');
```

Hope this Helps

Comment: I've tried that as well, it no longer includes the old code, but it includes the new code seperately and not through load_scripts.php. It's throwing errors as a result of being loading in the wrong order, is there anyway to get it to include it in the same place through load_scripts.php?

Comment: i'm guessing removing all of the script on load_scripts.php and enqueue them back in the right order.

Comment: It's not adding my script to load_scripts.php at all, its calling it as a separate javascript file.

Comment: that is because the use of wp_register_script with a url to the js file it suppose to load it separately and that is why if you need to keep order dependency you can use it in the  $dep array
in wp_enqueue_script( $handle, $src, $deps); and define your dependencies.

Comment: That was exactly the problem, everything working as it should now, much appreciated!

Comment: Glad it worked out.